# Can't pass array by reference on node.js. Some crazy behaviour here

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a little bit of code:

```
function changeArrElem( arr ) {
    arr = [ 23, 63, 85 ];
}

let arr = [];

console.log( arr.join() );
console.log( "" );

changeArrElem( arr );

console.log( arr.join() );
```

I expected to see initialized array in the function but no. I see nothing. Output is empty. How to pass array by reference to initialize it inside a function?

Comment: Well your array is empty from the start, since you never call the function that fills it.

Comment: @LioraHaydont, it's empty from the start sure. But then I call changeArrElem function and pass arr (I think) by reference but it's not. And finally after change that array inside changeArrElem (by reference) I have empty array again.

Comment: The result is expected. Your function mutates a local variable, not a pointer to an external variable. To set its content, you'd need to mutate the array object itself, not the variable. `arr.push( 23, 63, 85 )`

Comment: @rockstar, well, then how to clear array by reference inside that function?

Comment: @JavaRunner: `arr.length = 0;` will do it.

Comment: @rockstar, omg I didn't know it. I did: arr = []; - and it didn't help me. Your solution helped me. Thanks.

Comment: @JavaRunner If you still want to know why, then take a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259273/why-do-some-operations-not-alter-an-array-that-was-passed-to-a-function).